# Get javascript value without html or script tags

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, addtocart, jquery

I'm trying to get a product id value inside a add to cart button. The below code works getting the value in an alert.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery('#getChkBoxValues').click(function(){
        var chkBoxArray = [];
    jQuery('.checkbox-id:checked').each(function() {
            chkBoxArray.push(jQuery(this).val());
        });
    alert(chkBoxArray);
    });
});
</script>
<input type="button" value="Get Values" id="getChkBoxValues" />
```

Is there any way to get the value inside this button (below) where the number 5 is without any additional span, div, or script tags?

```
 <button id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="location.href='<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL); ?>checkout/cart/add?product=5&qty=1'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add All to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: Are you using this code in product list page or view page?

Answer (score 0):

You ca get the product id by this code

```
<button id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="location.href='<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL); ?>checkout/cart/add?product=<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>&qty=1'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add All to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: Yeah, but this is a little different. This is an also bought module that one can select more than one item to add to the cart. I think it has to be client side with  javascript? I tried getting it to work using the related products feature but the real add to cart button  and this new button (that's only for the also bought products) get the same values. So I'm wanting to use a new custom button.

Comment: In one cart button itself you need all the product which are selected . right?